# Move-Item not moving top folder in some cases

Tags: powershell

Trying to move all files and folders and how its behaving has me a little stumped.

Let's say we have a folder tree like Below

`Example Path
     Folder A
         FileA1
         FileA2
     Folder B
         FileB1`

When using the `Move-Item` command like this `move-Item -Path 'C:\Example Path\*' -Destination 'C:\Destination Path'` every time the first folder in the list just seems to get deleted. So the outcome of that command would be like this.

`Destination Path
     FileA1
     FileA2
     Folder B
         FileB1`

How would I get around this issue, Or am I doing something incorrectly here? Any help would be gladly appreciated.

Comment: Hm, this should work imho. However, can you try this: `Get-ChildItem C:\Example Path\ | Move-Item -Destination 'C:\Destination Path'`

Comment: Thanks for the Suggestions, that gave me the same outcome unfortunately.

Comment: Are you running the script as an administrator? If not, please give it a try.

Comment: Works just fine for me: http://imgur.com/a/jsQ8f Tested on PS5 on W10 and PS2 on W7 - both fine. What version of PS and OS do you use? Can you replay the issue on a test directories like mine? If not - it could be the folder access rights or something like this.

Comment: Yeah, Running as admin on windows 7 in PS5. Please see attached GIF. As you can see the BIN folder doesn't move with the contents but the other folder does.
http://i.imgur.com/f2Cjtif.gif

Comment: Could you try to move to another dir outside C:\Production? It seems to me that moving all content from dir to its subdir could be the issue...

Comment: Yeah, That's what I'm doing now which gets around the issue. But still the way its behaving doesn't really make any sense...

Answer (score 1):

i try this on my pc, it's working (PowerShell v5)

```
move-item -Path "C:\temp\Example Path" -Destination "C:\temp\Destination Path"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help though!

Comment: remove your * in "c:\production\\*"

Comment: That works, But it copies the Production Folder rather then the contents inside of it? Which is what I was aiming for.

Comment: But, I should be able to work with that. So thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating the destination folder manually before running the Move-Item command.

```bsh
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path 'C:\Destination Path'
Move-Item -Path 'C:\Example Path\*' -Destination 'C:\Destination Path'
```

https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13352#issuecomment-669025179